# Find a type in REPL?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
scala> val b = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
<console>:7: error: not found: type ArrayBuffer
       val b = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
                   ^
```

Can I use REPL to find the full path of ArrayBuffer and import it?

Comment: You can use [scalex.org](http://scalex.org)

Comment: Any IDE will be able to auto-import and have an ambiguity-resolution facility (after all, that's the point of packages), but I don't think the REPL is that advanced. Until someone develops a next-gen super-REPL, I'd use the scala API docs, kept open in a browser tab.

Answer (score 8):

you need to `import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`, classes (and objects) from scala.collection.mutable are not imported by default.